# How to setup a new homegroup in Win 7 when there is another homegroup setup on the network

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking, homegroup

I live in an appartment with three people and one of these people has setup a homegroup without my knowledge. He has left on a long holiday and won't be back for some time.

I need to create a group to share files with the other person who lives with me, so we need to setup our own homegroup or gain access to the current one.

Here are some facts about the situation to consider before answering:

1) The person who setup the homegroup is the only member of the homegroup
2) I am not joined to this homegroup
3) I don't know the password of this homegroup and I can't find it out without access to his computer or being a member of the homegroup.
4) I don't have access to the person who setup the homegroup's computer
5) When I go to "Network and Sharing center" in Windows 7, there is no option to create a new homegroup, there is only the option to join the existing one.

What is the solution here?

Comment: Do you have the option to leave the homegroup, even though you're not joined to it?

Comment: duplicate question: http://superuser.com/questions/718589/how-to-reset-password-for-a-homegroup-on-windows-7

Comment: There is no such option, the only option is "Available to join", which when clicked asks for the password.

Comment: That question has been deleted, Sickest.

Comment: you're asking the question that I answered for you in a slightly different way, trying to access the files of your friend's computer that you don't have access to. also i want to warn you, deleting question that have answers to them could result in a perm ban.

Comment: Sickest, nowhere am I saying I want to access his files. Infact, I'm trying to find a solution where I don't have to have access to his computer. I just want to create a homegroup! This shouldn't be so hard. Read the bottom part of my question for clarification on why this should be possible.

Comment: if the computer is not on the same network, windows 7 would not show that you are able to join another homegroup. But it is on the same network, and he is not perm gone from your apartment. So this question should in fact not exist because it's a hypothetical situation.

Comment: *edit*, ok I hope you're not trolling me here. So are you saying that if I turn off his computer I can then create another homegroup?

Comment: You don't need a password to leave a homegroup.  I'm confused by your question suggesting otherwise - post a screenshot of exactly what you are looking at please.

Comment: I'm not part of the homegroup, so I don't see how I can leave it if I'm not a member. I only have the invitation to join, here's a screenshot: http://oi58.tinypic.com/30su0ba.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to create a new homegroup with another homegroup on the network. I have not tested this, apply with caution.

1. Open up the Homegroup options within the control panel.
2. Disable the network adapter / disconnect the Ethernet cable. (Go to: Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings -> [click on Network Connection] -> Disable this network device).
3. Enable the network adapter and be prepared to create a new Homegroup quickly when the options appears.
4. When the create new Homegroup option appears and quickly enter a password, as it will fail if it has enough time to find the exisiting Homegroup.
5. Follow the prompts to set up and then insert your password on the other computers in the network like normal and it should automatically find the matching Homegroup.

Comment: Thanks Sickest, that dodgy workaround worked like a charm! Got there in the end.